# C - sockets - connect:result too large (windows)

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking

I've been a Unix programmer for a decent amount of time, and I know pretty well the system's socket API, I use it mostly for networking.

The thing is that I'm currently trying to create a cross-platform software, and so I began to learn how to compile my source code into windows executable files.

I've created a startup() function which does the simplest thing: connect to a server (of which IP is given), and return -1 on failure. On Linux my code runs smooth, but on Windows(7) I get the same error on some machines - "Connect()" function failed, errno: "Result too large" which (by what I understood) means it could no find any listening server on that IP, but on others it runs well.

Here is the code (win version):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>


#define ADDR "127.127.127.127"
#define PORT 8752


int startup(struct sockaddr_in sin)
{
  int sockfd, soaddr;
  WSADATA wsaData;

  if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return(-1);
  }

  soaddr = sizeof(sin);
  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, soaddr) == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "connect:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return(-1);
  }

  return sockfd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in sin;

  memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
  sin.sin_family  = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_port    = htons(PORT);
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDR);

  sockfd = startup(sin);

  // Code continues
  return(0);
}
```

note:ADDR has been changed for privacy reasons, but there is a working server on that machine

So, why exactly am I getting this error ?

Comment: I am not sure WSA's `socket` function changes `errno`. `errno` is a C/C++ run-time library artifact, and it is unlikely that a System API function can make changes to it. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifies you need to call `WSAGetLastError` to get the error code.

Comment: WinSock does not use `errno` at all.  `WSAGetLastError()` (and in some cases, `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)`) is the way to get WinSock error codes

Answer (score 3):

WinSock does not use `errno`, it uses `WSAGetLastError()` instead.

WinSock does not use file descriptors for sockets, it uses actual kernel objects.  On Windows, you need to use the `SOCKET` handle type, not `int`, for your socket variables (or at least type-cast `SOCKET` values to `(u)intptr_t` and then type-cast back to `SOCKET` when calling WinSock functions).

You can use the Win32 API `FormatMessage()` function to get a human readable string for a WinSock error code.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#define ADDR "127.127.127.127"
#define PORT 8752

__declspec(thread) char errmsg[256];

char* sockerr(int errcode)
{
    DWORD len = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, errcode, 0, errmsg, 255, NULL);
    if (len != 0)
        errmsg[len] = 0;
    else
        sprintf(errmsg, "error %d", errcode);
    return errmsg;
}

int startup()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup:%s\n", sockerr(ret));
        return(ret);
    }

    return(0);
}

void cleanup()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

SOCKET connectToServer(struct sockaddr_in sin)
{
    SOCKET sockfd;
    int soaddr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket:%s\n", sockerr(WSAGetLastError()));
        return(INVALID_SOCKET);
    }

    soaddr = sizeof(sin);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, soaddr) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "connect:%s\n", sockerr(WSAGetLastError()));
        closesocket(sockfd);
        return(INVALID_SOCKET);
    }

    return(sockfd);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SOCKET sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family  = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port    = htons(PORT);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDR);

    if (startup() != 0) {
      exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = connectToServer(sin);    
    if (sockfd != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        // ...
        closesocket(sockfd);
    }

    cleanup();
    return(0);
}
```

You will have to take these differences into consideration when writing cross-platform socket code.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are running `client socket` in windows machine.You need to load runtime libraries for windows as

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
```

You can refer to [Windows Client Socket Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx). Hope this works for you.

Comment: I see, but the thing is: the program works, but on some machines it doesn't and on others it does,  could it be the firewall blocking the communication ?

Comment: Yeah, you need to disable your firewall. I faced firewall problem when running Server Socket on windows. Try disabling firewall